# How to display informations from 3 tables with odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm a new developer on Python and just start develop an application with Odoo in python/xml and I have a problem to display the informations in a specific view.

I explain my problem : on a side, there are students; on an other, there are sessions of intership. All the students can register to all the session and they have to put a rank for this registration.
The problem is, I can't display the ranking of the registration.

Here my code,

The student class :

```
class Student(models.Model):
        _name = 'agsm.student'
        session_ids = fields.Many2many('agsm.session',
                                            relation="agsm_student_session",
                                            column1='student_id',
                                            column2='session_id')
```

The session class :

```
class Session(models.Model):
        _name='agsm.session'
        student_ids = fields.Many2many('agsm.student',
                                       relation='agsm_student_session',
                                       column1='session_id',
                                       column2='student_id')
```

And the class who do the relation

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    _name = 'agsm.student.session'
    session_id = fields.Many2one('agsm.session', string='Session')
    student_id = fields.Many2one('agsm.student', string='Student')
    rank = fields.Integer(default=5)
```

Whhat I want to do, is to display the rank in the student's form view. For the moment I have this block of code, but how can I add the display of the rank

```
<label for="session_ids"/>
<field name="session_ids">
    <tree string="Registered sessions">
        <field name="name"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Thank for the answer

Edit the new code is :
Student

```
class Student(models.Model):
    _name = 'agsm.student'
    session_ids = fields.Many2many('agsm.session',
                                        relation="agsm_student_session",
                                        column1='student_id',
                                        column2='session_id')
    session_ranks = fields.One2Many('agsm.student.session', 'student_id')
```

Rank

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    _name = 'agsm.student.session'

    session_id = fields.Many2one('agsm.session', string='Session')
    student_id = fields.Many2one('agsm.student', string='Student')
    rank = fields.Integer(default=5)
```

Session

```
class Session(models.Model):
    _name='agsm.session'
    student_ids = fields.Many2many('agsm.student',
                                   relation='agsm_student_session',
                                   column1='session_id',
                                   column2='student_id')
```

Student view

```
<label for="session_ranks"/>
<field name="session_ranks">
    <tree string="Registered sessions" editable="bottom">
        <field name="session_id"/>
        <field name="rank"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your need, you should do the following changes:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    _name = 'agsm.student'
    session_ids = fields.Many2many('agsm.session',
                                        relation="agsm_student_session",
                                        column1='student_id',
                                        column2='session_id')
    session_ranks = fields.One2Many('agsm.student.session', 'student_id')
```

in the view

```
<label for="session_ranks"/>
<field name="session_ranks">
    <tree string="Registered sessions" editable="bottom">
        <field name="session_id"/>
        <field name="rank"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

The *editable="bottom"* attribute avoids the need of a middle-view between student and session.

Comment: Thanks, but when I change the code I have a warning : WARNING Field agsm.student.session_ranks with unknown comodel_name 'agsm.student.session' and then an ERROR werkzeug: Error on request: ... KeyError: 'student_id'
How can I change that ? :/

Comment: Did you update the module after your changes? You also need to restart openerp before update...

Comment: Yes, the openerp is shutdown then restart and I launch with the following command : ./odoo.py -u agsm (on the folder ~/python/odoo$). In theory, the module is correctly update, right ?

Comment: I think you need to add also the *-d* parameter as in [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/cmdline.html) But the best would be by using the web interface. In the Settings menu look for Local Module item, search your module and update it.

Comment: Work better with the web interface. But know, the error is in the student's form : "The field 'rank' doesn't not exist"

Comment: that's quite strange. Could you please edit your question to show the actual code?

Comment: Everything seems normal, it just should work. I'do the following checks: restart the server and update the module paying attention on the log when the file containing the view is called (maybe post also the log). check the database to see if the field rank has been created into the agsm.student.session table. check the __init__ file to check if the .py file declaring the agsm.student.session model is imported. check the ir.model.field to see if the rank field exists for that model.

Comment: Ok i'm feeling so stupid ... the file where the class rank is init wasn't import ... Now i have correct that, the fields rank correctly exist in the model. But, i'm not out of problem : when i try to see the form view of a student, there is again an error : ProgrammingError: column agsm_student_session.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "agsm_student_session".id FROM "agsm_student_session"... But in the database, the field "id" exist in the model agsm.student.session :/

Comment: I've done that... that's how I knew what to check :)
Could this be your issue: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-8-programmingerror-column-id-does-not-exist-87600

Comment: So if i'm correctly understanding, I have to change the "session_ranks = fields.One2many('agsm.student.session', 'student_id')" into "session_ranks = fields.One2many('agsm_student_session', 'student_id')" ? I try that, but the error remain

Comment: I think Daryl is right, but maybe instead of follow fix suggested by the link it is better for you to remove the whole module, control that all table in the db have been drop (and so db related *ir* fields) then install the module again, this time removing the session_ids field.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BOTH OF YOU =D it's work correctly with your explanation, yeah :D

Answer (score 0):

You would need to not use many2many tables because you are using the bridging table as more than just a bridging table.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    _name = 'agsm.student'
    student_session_ids = fields.One2many('agsm.student.session','Student Sessions')

class Rank(models.Model):
    _name = 'agsm.student.session'
    session_id = fields.Many2one('agsm.session', string='Session')
    student_id = fields.Many2one('agsm.student', string='Student')
    rank = fields.Integer(default=5)

class Session(models.Model):
    _name='agsm.session'
```

The view

```
<label for="student_session_ids"/>
<field name="student_session_ids" >
    <tree string="Registered sessions">
        <field name="session_id"/>
        <field name="rank"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I change the code I have a warning : WARNING Field agsm.student.session_ranks with unknown comodel_name 'agsm.student.session' and then an ERROR werkzeug: Error on request: ... KeyError: 'Student Sessions' How can I change that ? :/

Comment: Hi. Sorry about the late reply.  Did you get this fixed?

Comment: Hi, yes I fix this problem but now i have a second ... the error is in the student's form : "The field 'rank' doesn't not exist"

Comment: hmm... Can't see anything wrong with your code that you edited.  Try removing rank from the xml and getting it to a point where you can access the site.  Then go into settings -> models and make sure that rank exists in the relevant model.  Also, always make sure that you restart odoo when you make a change to a python file.

Comment: Ok i'm feeling so stupid ... the file where the class rank is init wasn't import ... Now i have correct that, the fields rank correctly exist in the model. But, i'm not out of problem : when i try to see the form view of a student, there is again an error : ProgrammingError: column agsm_student_session.id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "agsm_student_session".id FROM "agsm_student_session"... But in the database, the field "id" exist in the model agsm.student.session :/